# How to write a dynamic server ip address based android application?

Tags: android, dynamic, ip

I would like to run an android application which will get data from a system(server)with dynamic IP address.

Problem: Using an IP address I will generate an apk and will run the app. Even if the IP address changes in the meanwhile I don't want to get the 'IP address not Reachable' error. Is it possible to write a code which will run the application even the IP address changes often? If yes can anybody post that code or tell me the procedure to do so? So thanks for looking into this issue and for giving solution to this.

Comment: You're looking for DNS.

Comment: You are looking for Dynamic DNS -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS